# Question regarding duplicate contents

Tags: seo, blog, link-building

If I create blogs using different blog domains with the same content (own content) and link it with my original website using targeted anchor text, will it harm my SEO of my original website? The original website is genuine and doesn't have any copied contents. I'm using cross-domain canonicalization to some extend, but can't use it in all the articles and blogs. Will the duplicate contents from my own different blogs will hurt my original site just because it links to it?

Answer (score 3):

You must be aware of recent Google algorithm updates. If not, read WebMasterWorld forum where people shared their experience on how they lost their ranks because of duplicate content and poor link profiles.

I strongly recommend not to publish duplicate content on multiple blogs just to generate backlinks for your main website. It will no longer help in organic search. Rather than give your effort on publishing original and well formatted content that can help your readers.

Comment: Thank you PeggyP. I do understand. But the internet is filled with duplicate contents. I was just hoping the duplicate content issue sticks only if we are doing it to the main website. Thought links obtained from duplicate content blogs won't effect the main sites seo negatively instead helped the keyword rankings (my experience backed me up). After all these Google algo updates, frankly none of them hurt my website just because of this reason. I think practically we can get away with this technique, if we are not doing any other oldschool, intense spammy stuff.

Comment: Thats true but i am still not getting the benefits are seeking by generating links from duplicate content. I am sure, if you start generating low quality baclinks, it may harm your website.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peggy. I just needed to confirm how bad this situation is even I got away with it.

Answer (score 2):

Of course. Definitely It will harm your website. Because unique content is one of the major SEO factor and if any website gets backlink from duplicate content then it will definitely hurt by Google. Google's latest penguin update (Penguin 2.0) affect all the websites that follows link farming methods. It also affect the websites that get backlink from bad content also. So if you use several blogs with same content with link target to your site, its a dangerous one for your site. So my advice is build a single blog with your own content and get a backlink to your site or build multiple blogs with different unique content.

Comment: @John Sanjay: putting your link with all your posts is not really welcoming here.

Answer (score 2):

When you get backlinks from another website, authority of this website is very important for SEO of your website. If you decide to create a spammy blogs network, Google will apply a sanction to your network and thus to your website.

A good solution for SEO of your website would be to create a blogs network with relevant and no duplicate content refering to your field of competence and put just few backlinks to your website from each blog.

Comment: Guys, Just imagine this situation, two blog domains, having same content, both having massive user engagements and views as its having very useful and updated content, both having their own organic social media exposure. Does the equation change then? Just being curious :)

Comment: It doesn't change, if you have duplicate content, you're off for SEO.

Comment: It is depending upon % of duplicate content/ domain authority and types of user engagement. I never seen such websites having 100% duplicate content with better search visibilities.

Comment: Ok PeggyP but we talk about two websites with duplicate content, not a duplicate content between a page and another. In general, between two websites, there is a lot of duplicate content and Google doesn't like it at all.